# Error JBoss AS7 Maven + Spring + JSF + Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

Put the meta- INF in src / main / resources and data source created in the standalone.xml and added the seat module but When the beginning of this error que In the last paragraphs to Low .

**Class Atleta**

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDF_CLUBE")
    private Clube clube;
```

**Class Clube**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "clube")
    private List<Atleta> atletas;
```

**datasource standalone.xml**

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasource/OnzeVencedorDB" pool-name="OnzeVencedorDB"
                    enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OnzeVencedorDB</connection-url>
                    <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>root</password>
                    </security>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>

<driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
```

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/OnzeVencedor</context-root>
  <resource-ref>
      <res-ref-name>datasource/onzeVencedorDB</res-ref-name>
      <jndi-name>datasource/OnzeVencedorDB</jndi-name>
</resource-ref> 
</jboss-web>
```

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <!-- Configuracao do Spring -->
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <!-- Configuracao do JSF -->
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <resource-ref>
      <res-ref-name>datasource/onzeVencedorDB</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
         <res-auth>Container</res-auth>      
  </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Seta anotaçoes para serem usadas pelo Spring -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Define o pacote onde o Spring vai procurar por beans anotados -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.senac.onzevencedor.service,br.com.senac.onzevencedor.dao" />

    <!-- Define que as transaçoes irao ser anotadas -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Configuraçao do banco de dados -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"> 
         <property name="OnzeVencedorDB" value="java:jboss/datasource/OnzeVencedorDB"/> 
     </bean> 

    <!-- Configuraçao do Hibernate -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="onzeVencedorDB" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" >
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configuracao do gerente de transacoes do Spring -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="onzeVencedorPu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasource/OnzeVencedorDB</jta-data-source>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="${schema}" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.eviction.strategy" value="LRU" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.eviction.wake_up_interval" value="2000" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.eviction.max_entries" value="5000" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.expiration.lifespan" value="60000" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.expiration.max_idle" value="30000" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Error**

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.OnzeVencedor.OnzeVencedor.env.datasource.OnzeVencedorDB (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.OnzeVencedor.OnzeVencedor.env.datasource.customerDB] 

13:15:00,305 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.OnzeVencedor.OnzeVencedor.env.datasource.customerDBjboss.naming.context.java.module.OnzeVencedor.OnzeVencedor.env.datasource.OnzeVencedorDBMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.module.OnzeVencedor.OnzeVencedor.env.datasource.customerDBjboss.naming.context.java.module.OnzeVencedor.OnzeVencedor.env.datasource.OnzeVencedorDB]"]}}}
```

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: Thank you! for answer, but still with error JBAS014775: New missing/unsatisfied dependencies: service jboss.naming.context.java.module.OnzeVencedor.OnzeVencedor.env.datasource.OnzeVe‌​ncedorDB (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.OnzeVencedor.OnzeVencedor.env.datasource.custom‌​erDB]

Answer (score 1):

At this [link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/124699-spring-3-2-jboss-7-1-1-how-to-get-the-datasource-from-jndi) there is more or less the same problem .

Change this configuration

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"> 
     <property name="OnzeVencedorDB" value="java:jboss/datasource/OnzeVencedorDB"/> 
 </bean>
```

in

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasource/OnzeVencedorDB"/>
```

add also xml declaration like below

```
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
```

Comment: Thank you! for answer, but still with error JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.OnzeVencedor.OnzeVencedor.env.datasource.OnzeVencedorDB (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.OnzeVencedor.OnzeVencedor.env.datasource.customerDB]